# Change owner and group of all files and directories

Tags: linux, group, chown

I tried changing the owner and group of all files and directories Vincent and staff respectively in my terminal but its not working.

I tried using
chown -R Vincent:staff*...

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard to change the owner of both files and directories like:

`chown -R Vincent:staff <path>/*`

Or if you want to give different owners to files and directories then you can use find to select the files and directories:

For files:

`find <path>/ -type f  -exec chown Vincent:staff {} \;`

For directories:

`find <path>/ -type d  -exec chown Vincent:staff {} \;`

You can use the same commands to run `chmod`, if you want to change the permissions.

Answer (score -1):

What is exactly the command that you used? The following one should run:

```
chown -R Vincent:staff myfolder/*
```